# Computational Complexity: confused about contradiction in proof that most decision problems can't be computed

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm a bit confused about this proof, which is given at 13 mins in this lecture here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moPtwq_cVH8

The proof relies on the fact that programs need to be finite, making the set of all programs less than the set of all functions.   That should imply that there's a theoretical maximum sized program, because lets say the set of all programs S, which is claimed to be finite, has size N.   Now, if we take the largest program in N, and add 1 bit to it, we've now created a program not in S, which contradicts the statement that S is the set of all programs.

But for any program of an arbitrarily large size K, you can make a program of size K+1.  This means there can't be a maximum sizes program.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood. Each program is finite. Not the set of programs.

Comment: If each program was finite, wouldn't that imply the set of all programs must be finite, since there are a finite permutation of a finite number of bits?

Comment: @ruisen No. And no idea why you think that. I can write a program of length 1, a program of length 2, a program of length 3, and so on. Infinitely many programs, each of finite size.